# how to insert variable in SQL LIKE query in flask/python?

Tags: python, sqlite

i have this code:

```
text = request.form.get("searchText")
        print(text)
        result = dbSession.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM books WHERE
            (isbn LIKE '%:text%') OR (title LIKE '%:text%')
            OR (author LIKE '%:text%') LIMIT 10",
            { "text": text }
        ).fetchall()
```

I am getting error like this as is the text = q:

```
(isbn LIKE '%'q'%')
```

I think it has to be translated like this:

```
(isbn LIKE '%q%')
```

What should i do?

Comment: Hmm, it's not so simple with a dict of parameters. You normally have `LIKE ?` and then concatenate the `%` on either side of the parameter values (i.e. that are passed to the string, you don't include them in the string itself)

Comment: in the tutorial i am following a query is done like this:  db.execute("SELECT * FROM flights WHERE id = :id", {"id": flight_id}), i think i am following it right?

Comment: My comment was specifically in reference to using LIKE because you have to supply the `%` outside of the query string, concatenated to the parameters. Or, at least you do with SQLite. It's not immediately clear to me how you would do that cleanly when supplying a dictionary of parameters.

Comment: Try: `"SELECT * FROM books WHERE (isbn LIKE ':text') OR (title LIKE ':text') OR (author LIKE ':text') LIMIT 10", { "text": '%' + text + '%'}`